# SharePoint 2013 Permissions - A.D and SharePoint 2013 on premis

Tags: permissions, document, access, delete, edit

I wonder if anyone could advise on this. I have a user that cant use all the functions within a document library, edit delete etc. To me this points to permissions.

I have checked the site permissions and the user is in a ad group that has "Full Control, Limited Access" Given via a A.D group.

However for some reason this person has also been given "Edit" directly via the sharepoint site.

This user needs to be able to edit / delete documents - could this be a permissions conflict - on one hand they have permissions yet another they dont?

Could any advise on what best course of action to take to remedy this.

Many Thanks
James